# Kafka producer/consuper Topic not authorized

Tags: apache-kafka

Whenever I try to connect to kafka to producer/consume I get "Not authorized for topics [test2]"

If I turn off the authorization I get authenticated successfully, so the authentication works and only the authorization doesn't.

ACL authorization with kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer not working.

config/server.properties

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://kafka3:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol= SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
delete.topic.enable=false
```

logs/kafka-authorizer

```
[2019-04-06 13:24:05,693] DEBUG No acl found for resource Topic:LITERAL:test2, authorized = false (kafka.authorizer.logger) [2019-04-06 13:24:05,695] INFO Principal = User:alice is Denied Operation = Describe from host = 10.0.9.20 on resource = Topic:LITERAL:test2(kafka.authorizer.logger)uper.users=User:admin
```

server's jaas file:

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin"
    user_admin="admin"
    user_alice="alice";
};
```

bin/kafka-server-start.sh

```
$base_dir/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$base_dir/../config/jaas-kafka-server.conf kafka.Kafka "$@"
```

acl output:

```
Current ACLs for resource `Topic:LITERAL:test2`:
    User:alice has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of `server.properties` and the full trace with the errors?

Comment: it may be because you are indeed authenticated (that's what jaas do), but you are not authorized (that's what ACLs do). Check your current acls and look if the user has permissions

Comment: Instead of posting non-readable configuration in the comments, edit your post and include it in your question.

Comment: @PyTux are you trying to consume or produce? or both?

Comment: @aran I want to consume and produce from different users

Answer (score 1):

User `alice` is currently only authorized to `Write` to that topic. You would also likely want to add the ACLs `Describe` and `Read` to be able to properly produce and consume to your existing topic.

The `kafka-acls` tool provides convenience options `--consumer` and `--producer` when adding ACLs to a topic. Otherwise, you can use `--operation` to add specific operations such as `Describe`. By adding `Describe`, you'd remove the log you're currently seeing in `logs/kafka-authorizer`.

Comment: Thank you but I tried with --consumer and --producer but still get the log message:User:alice is Denied Operation = Describe

Comment: This is the main issue:DEBUG No acl found for resource Topic:LITERAL:test2 And I tried to apply the acl on both zookeepers and brokers and I can list them and I see them there associated with the topic and also in the zookeepers znodes but kafka can;t find the acl on login for the particular user

Answer (score 1):

As you would like consume and produce message from a particular topic with turning on ACL, then you need to apply ACL on the topic to consume and produce message to it. You need to do it through a super user like kafka.

Login to a kafka broker then use below command :

sudo su - kafka

kinit -kt /path/to/keytabs/kafka.service.keytab kafka/serviceprincipal name@domain name
  (you can get it from kafka jaas file)

Then from kafka directory execute these command :

bin/kafka-acls --add --allow-principal User:* --consumer --topic test2 --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=:2181 --group *

Similarly for producer to push message to topics :

bin/kafka-acls.sh --add --allow-principal User:* --producer --topic test2 --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=:2181

Above command will apply ACLs to all users . You can restrict it by specifying individual user name instead of '*' in the command.

** Remember you should not have any text file or any other file other than kafka installed file/directory in the bin directory as part of kafka installation.

To get more info on ACL(addind/removing,listing) go to below link:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html

Comment: Thank you, I am not using any kerberos or any other auth system, just plain SASL authentication and ACL authorizaition, additionally I applied ACLs to --topic test2 but it seems like the authorizer is broken because I am able to list the ACLs and I see that they are there but the user cant get authorized because when I try with the super user I am able to do all or when I turn on the option for if no acl found allow everyone that works which means Kafka doesnt really associates ACL to the topic altough I can list them and I see they are there